# Manage Supervisord process - Auto start on boot/Auto start upon it crash

Tags: linux, unix, ansible, supervisord

We are using Supervisord for our apache server process monitoring.

So i would like to keep supervisor process always up for the below two scenarios:

1. Autostart supervisor upon server reboot(Without init.d help)
2. Autostart supervisor process upon it crashes while running.

We also have ansible installed.

It would be really great if someone can share their thoughts on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start with ansible - you can use it to install supervisor (example with apt module, use [yum module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/yum_module.html) if you have to):

```
- name: Install Supervisord
  apt: name=supervisor state=present update_cache=yes
  become: yes
```

and deploy the necessary supervisor configuration files (using the [copy module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html)).

```
- name: Deploy config file
  copy: src=yourconfigfile.conf dest=/etc/supervisor/conf.d/apache.conf mode=644
  become: yes
```

To autostart supervisor itself you need to just enable it (you can use the [service module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/service_module.html) - enabled: yes). To have the supervisor controlled programs to autostart and autorestart, set the proper directives in the program configuration files. Example:

```
[program:apache]
command=apache2ctl -c "ErrorLog /dev/stdout" -DFOREGROUND
# this would autostart apache
autostart=true
# this would autorestart it if it crashes
autorestart=true
startretries=1
startsecs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/myapache.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/myapache.out.log
user=root
killasgroup=true
stopasgroup=true
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion, am trying to use "service" module, and getting the following error. 

FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "standard in must be a tty\n"}

Any Suggestion?

Comment: I had a similar issue with a handler for supervisor. It failed to restart. Try with the `sleep` option of the service module (it won't work if you have systemd), or simply use the `shell` module and the a `shell: service supervisor restart`.

Comment: Hi @13nilux, it's really great to hear from you again and spending your precious time for this question. Apart from the modules we discussed above, can v use "Anisible crontab" module to make an entry in crontab for autostart supervisor on boot?? if it is there, can u share some example pls..

Comment: supervisor will start at boot if you enable it. Do it with service module (not to restart/start/stop - as of the issue discussed above, but only to enable it) like this: `service: name=supervisor enabled=yes`

Comment: ok, great.. so wer this will make an entry btw.. i mean in which file(in linux) to start supervisor on server reboot

Comment: When you install supervisor it comes with a daemon, which you can manage via `service` or `systemd`, depending on the init you have chosen. `systemctl enable supervisor` will make supervisor start after system reboot. To do it with ansible, use `service: name=supervisor enabled=yes`.

Comment: Also, the above said command i.e "service: name=supervisor enabled=yes" require any entry in "ini.d" directory ?? i mean some "supervisor" script to start/stop supervisor?

Comment: What distro are you setting this on?What happens if you type "service supervisor start" in your shell?

Comment: When i type "service supervisor start", am getting "supervisor: unrecognized service." but when i type "superviosr status" or simply "supervisor" it is displaying the "supervisor process" currectly as a "Running State".

Comment: Am having "GNU/Linux".

Comment: Do you have systemd or sysvinit?

Comment: No, when i try "systemd", it says "command not found", also the case is same for "upstart", only "initd" is available.

Comment: ok, you have sysvinit. Usually supervisor (or any program) comes with a file for `/etc/init.d`, but this might not be your case.

Comment: have a look at the init scripts for supervisor here - https://github.com/Supervisor/initscripts - you have to check your distro before choosing a suitable one (`more /etc/*-release` will show you your distro version).

Comment: Hi.. Am having this command in crontab, added using Ansible cron module. "@reboot supervisord -c *conffilepath", but this is not working as part of reboot. But working fine while executing manually, and supervisor is starting fine. Do u have any idea y the @reboot command not working at server reboot??